# Three.js performance with high number of objects

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am working on a project which needs rendering of thousands of unique meshes of building models. My objects need to be selectable and they will have their data (other than geometry) attached to them.

Since number of objects/meshes has a big impact on the rendering performance, I merge my objects into a few huge meshes and create "pseudo meshes" which just hold information about the indexes of the mesh's triangles and the other data attached. I am able to render each mesh with their own color and user is able to pick them separately.

However transparency and render order is making things hard for me. I managed to render my scene with transparent and non-transparent objects by merging them to separate meshes.

My problem is not being able to highlight the picked objects effectively. I want the highlighting to be a non-transparent color. If a transparent object is picked I change the associated triangles' color attribute to match my highlight color with opacity of 1.0. But this does not work as I intend to because, since the merged mesh's material is transparent, the render order for it won't change although I set the opacity of its' triangles as 1.0. Result is poorly ordered objects on the screen.

I know I could use MultiMaterial but then number of drawcalls -may or may not- increase enormously if the user selects high number of objects. So I am looking for a better solution that will keep the same performance whatever happens.

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?